# Snap Viewport Camera?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, customization, snapping, navigation

There's a navigation option in 3Dcoat where you can just hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button while rotating  your view and it will snap to nearest elevation (front back side etc).

This renders the need for switching views null. I know there is something similar in Blender but would love to remap what ever that option is to <kbd>Shift</kbd> in the keymap menu.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 3):

You can hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while dragging your view angle around. This will snap the angle to the default numpad angles.

Comment: I never knew that. Thanks, I must try that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes thats what I am currently using which is not ideal as I want to do my keys layout slightly differently. Ideally I would know the name of this function so I can find it in the key custom menu in prefs but cant for the life of me find it :S